# Using CakePHP, ZURB Foundation, and jQuery to design and build CRUD functionality for a self-HABTM (many-to-many) related model

Tags: jquery, cakephp, many-to-many

I'll start by describing what I'm trying to do, which is to build a specialized CMS. Prepared HTML content is placed in my Node model class, and each Node will have a unique title besides the surrogate key provided by CakePHP. That part is easy.

But now I want to store relations between Nodes. Of which there will be thousands (and so of course I want to build like it's gonna be millions!). There are going to be many different types of relations, like "requires", "recommends", "suggests", and "motivates", but they all relate one node to another. And for now, they're all one-way.

I understand why each of these relations will require a dedicated database table. My difficulty is in creating CRUD for these relations. Users must be able explicitly define these relations--they cannot be deduced from the content of the nodes.

What I'd like is for a user to be presented with an expandable list of autocomplete fields. The user may begin typing part of the title of a Node to which they would like to form a relation, and the autocomplete field will display a list of Nodes whose titles contain that part in their title. The user may then select a listed Node to fill in the field, or they may continue narrowing the list of matching Nodes by typing further. If the user needs to make multiple relations, they may add additional autocomplete fields by hitting the appropriate button.

This presents two big challenges. Firstly, due to the large number of Nodes, the autocomplete fields can't use a local list that can be searched with JavaScript. The fields will have to rely on the server to do the searching for them. Secondly, the server will need to be able to deal with a variable number of relation fields being submitted.

I'm wondering how to tackle these problems at a high level. I have CakePHP, ZURB Foundation, and jQuery at my fingertips, but there's a lot of stuff that needs to be connected together. I was hoping someone could help me plan out how the pieces will fit together. How can CakePHP be made aware of a variable number of input fields, and how can it provide an interface for getting Node title search results?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to have one table per "connecton type", if your DB can't handle millions of records the DB doesn't deserve to be called DB. If it becomes an issue one day then you can still optimize it or use a cache for that table and its most often queries records.

I wouldn't use jquery for that after I've tried Angular.js. Jquery is a huge mess compared with Angular. I would use Jquery now only for some UI-candy but not for handling the data.

Use Angular + CakePHP and a RESTful API to communicate between your frontend and your application and use Angular to handle the data binding.

And honestly I've been teased to down vote that question because it doesn't contain any code and its overall a "broad" question which can be answered in many ways an is influenced by opinions.

Comment: "it doesn't contain any code and its overall a "broad" question which can be answered in many ways an is influenced by opinions." And yet you answered it, which means here it sits 8 years later instead of being automatically cleaned up!